# Does the g++ compiler view arrays of strings and integers differently?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, gcc

I can't seem to get an array of strings declared inside of a function.

```
void foo(string arr[], int arrSize) {
    string temp[arrSize]; //Results in error shown below
    int temp2[arrSize]; // Compiles fine
}
```

I'm getting a compile-time error that states: **variable length array of non-POD element type 'string' (aka 'basic_string, allocator >') ...[a...**

I've tried declaring the arrSize parameter as constant with `void foo(string arr[], const int arrSize);` and even declaring a new constant integer inside of the function and initializing it to arrSize but both still result in the same error. The only way I've been able to get this to compile is by using a magic number when declaring my temp string array.

Also, I'm aware that I could just use a vector instead, but I'm just wondering why this behavior is taking place.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Neither of them Standard C++. Now it all depends on the compiler as to how it has implemented VLA.

Comment: And it's still an interesting question why GCC treats them differently.

Comment: C++ array sizes must be compile-time constant, not just `const`. The fact that `int temp2[arrSize];` works is a compiler extension.

Comment: *"non-POD element type"* is a good place to start some research.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Yeah that was where I started looking. So since a string is an array of characters it isn't considered "plain old data," and as such has different rules?

Comment: A string is not an array of characters. std::string is a class, what it stores is up to the implementer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it treats them differently. As you can see from the error message g++ allows the creation of variable length arrays only if the elements are POD types.

As to the why I'm not sure if there is a technical reason, but as this is a non-standard extension carried over from C, one possible explanation is that it was trivial to implement it for c-compatible structs (which is what POD essentially are) and no one bothered to extend this to non POD-types.

In response to the comment: A `std::string` is not just an array of characters, but a much more complex class, that may allocate the data somewhere on the heap (just like a `std::vector<int>` isn't just an array of ints).

Update: An interesting datapoint from the paper proposing [Runtime-sized arrays with automatic storage duration](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3639.html) for c++:

> There is no reason to limit the feature to PODs as array element types, thus such a limitation is not proposed.

So it seems to really be a case of: "No one came around to actually implement it"

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.